# Convert string to WdPaperSize object - Word VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm developing a Word Add-in (VSTO).

I have a xml file with page size values, like this:

```
<entry name="Size">wdPaperA3</entry>
```

I'm trying to get these values and set them in a WdPaperSize object, like this:

```
WdPaperSize val = this.getFromXML("Size");
foreach (Section i in doc.Sections)
   {
      i.PageSetup.PaperSize = val;
   }
```

But I get these errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPaperSize'
```

and

```
'WdPaperSize' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

How to convert string to WdPaperSize object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WdPaperSize` is an enumeration.  Try:

```
i.PageSetup.PaperSize = (WdPaperSize) Enum.Parse(typeof(WdPaperSize), val);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great.